# Two things in the form dependent on each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my form I have this HTML:

```
<select name="clientData[first]" >
    <option value="0">without</option>  
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="clientData[second]">
```

And what I have to do is if I have selected `without` I can type something in the `<input>`. If I have selected something else then the `<input>` should be disabled. If I first type something in `<input>` I disable the `<select>`
And I don't know how to do that. Can anybody help?

Comment: so what exactly you want to ask?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hook to the `change` event of the `select` and then toggle the `input` as required. Try this:

```js
$('select').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '0') {
        $('input').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('input').prop('disabled', true).val('');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="clientData[first]">
  <option value="0">without</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="clientData[second]">
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in jQuery

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    if($('option:selected').text() == 'without') {
        $('input').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
        $('input').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

You need to listen for a change on the select tag.

You can use the selected selector to select any element with the selected state. You can then assign properties with prop.

Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/tu1au8aw/

Comment: false and true must be without quotes .. with quotes you change it to just string .. .prop('disabled', false); and prop('disabled', true);

Comment: I just realized that and I fixed it

Comment: But in your case if I change without to anything else and then change back to without I can't still to type something...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').change(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == '0') {
        $('input').prop('disabled', false);
      }
        else {
          $('input').prop('disabled', true);
        }
      });

    $('input').on('input', function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $('select').prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
        $('select').prop('disabled', true);
      }
    });
```

```html
<select name="clientData[first]">
  <option value="0">without</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="clientData[second]">
```